# Platform Event Channels and Channel Members

Tags: platform-event

So having gone thru the documentation for Platform Events with Filters, I started implementing it.

- What I am trying to do is to create a Platform Event Channel Member for each user who will be subscribing to the platform event.
- In this way, I can cut down the number of delivery events sent when a platform event is published.
- So I added a field on my platform event called `Subscriber__c`.
- So again, as per documentation, for each applicable user, I first created a platform event channel, and then a corresponding platform event channel member with the filter criteria set to `"Subscriber__c='userId'"`.  This is working fine.

But I then read on the Platform Event Allocation help page that there is a maximum limit of 100 custom channels that can be created.  Right now I am not up to 100 users, but that may change in the future.

So is there a better way to do this?

It appears that for what I am trying to do, I cannot create one user-independent platform event channel and then one platform event channel member for each user; if I do this, then I can only subscribe at the channel level, and not at the channel member level.

Comment: Why do you want an independent channel for every user?  This sounds like a bit of an X-Y problem to me.

Comment: There are limits on how many platform events can be delivered daily.  I am using filters to keep the number down.

Comment: why not create a "subscriber group" concept and then have channels per group?

Comment: @cropredy not sure what you mean. Can you clarify?

Comment: you assert that 1 channel member per user will exhaust the 100 limit; so assign users to "groups" and have the channel member be per "group". Then once the platform events are delivered to the group, at the subscriber end, filter again using Flow so only the message relevant to that user is displayed/processed